# decompress a file containing multiple concatenated zlib streams

Tags: javascript, node.js, zlib

How do you decompress a file containing multiple concatenated zlib streams in node? I can do this easily as below in python but in node's docs it's rather unclear as to how to get the unused tail. Using `inSr.pipe(zlib.createInflate()).pipe(outSr)` only gives me the first chunk, so what would be the equivalent of the following in node?

```
obj = zlib.decompressobj()
with open(args.inpath, 'rb') as in_sr, open(args.outpath, 'wb') as out_sr:
    while True:
        if obj.unused_data:
            contents = obj.unused_data
            obj = zlib.decompressobj()
        else:
            contents = in_sr.read(cache_size)
        if not contents:
            break
        out_sr.write(obj.decompress(contents))
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: @FelipeCruz Don't quite remember, but probably not as I usually post answers if I solved them.